# Python how to generate additional values between two row-values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame of two float columns. I want to create additional float values in between the row-values. Incidentally, I want to stack the generated values into new rows between them. I have two methods do it.

```
df = 
       data1    data2   
0      1.913  8.284000
1     13.060  8.261000
2     24.041  8.252000
```

I want to generate 5 additional rows between rows in above dataframe. I would like to achieve it in two methods.

**Method1: expected output** is given below. In this, addtional values are created in data1 column as `np.linspace(1.913,13.060,7)` as given below from index 0 to 6. The data2 column maintains a constant value 8.284 in these additional rows.

```
newdf1 = 
       data1           data2   
0      1.913          8.284000   ## Original row
1      3.77083333     8.284000   ## Generated row  
2      5.62866667     8.284000   ## Generated row  
3      7.4865         8.284000   ## Generated row   
4      9.34433333     8.284000   ## Generated row  
5      11.20216667    8.284000   ## Generated row             
6      13.060         8.261000   ## Original 
7                     8.261000
.                     8.261000
.
                      8.261000
12     24.041        8.252000
```

**Method2: expected output** is given below. The data1 column follows same approach as in above Method1. Now, data2 column values are also mapped. Ex, `np.linspace(8.284000,8.261000,7)`

```
newdf2 = 
       data1           data2   
0      1.913          8.284000     ## Original row
1      3.77083333     8.28016667   ## Generated row  
2      5.62866667     8.27633333   ## Generated row  
3      7.4865         8.2725       ## Generated row   
4      9.34433333     8.26866667   ## Generated row  
5      11.20216667    8.26483333   ## Generated row             
6      13.060         8.261000     ## Original 
7      
.

12     24.041        8.252000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest splitting your task in two parts:

1. Inserting (empty) extra rows to the DataFrame
2. Filling those extra rows according to your given rules (interpolation).

For the first part, a (admittedly complex) list comprehension will do. For the second part, the pandas `DataFrame`'s method `.interpolate()` is your friend.

But let's not get ahead of ourselves. We first generate your original `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data1': [1.913, 13.060, 24.041], 'data2': [8.284, 8.261, 8.252]})
```

## 1. Inserting extra rows between existing values

Now we generate a `dict` containing the original data, as well extra values in between (`NaN`s). We then create a new `DataFrame` from the `dict`:

```
line_ins = 5 # Number of lines to insert
res_dict = {col: [y for val in df[col] for y in [val] + [np.nan]*line_ins][:-line_ins] for col in df.columns}
df_new = pd.DataFrame(res_dict)
```

Explanation of list comprehension: for each value (`val`) in the `DataFrame`'s column, we also add five `np.nan`'s (`[val] + [np.nan]*line_ins`).
In the end we cut of the last five values from the generated list (`[:-line_ins]`), because we don't want to have the additional rows after the last value. Finally, we flatten the list (hence the stacked list comprehension).

## 2. Determining values of new rows (interpolation)

#### Method 1

In this case we want to linearly interpolate the column `data1`, while for `data2` we want to use the existing values:

```
df_new['data1'] = df_new['data1'].interpolate()
df_new['data2'] = df_new['data2'].interpolate(method='pad')
```

The resulting `df_new` contains the following:

```
        data1  data2
0    1.913000  8.284
1    3.770833  8.284
2    5.628667  8.284
3    7.486500  8.284
4    9.344333  8.284
5   11.202167  8.284
6   13.060000  8.261
7   14.890167  8.261
8   16.720333  8.261
9   18.550500  8.261
10  20.380667  8.261
11  22.210833  8.261
12  24.041000  8.252
```

#### Method 2

In this case we want to linearly interpolate both columns, making things even easier:

```
df_new = df_new.interpolate()
```

And the contents of the resulting `df_new`:

```
        data1     data2
0    1.913000  8.284000
1    3.770833  8.280167
2    5.628667  8.276333
3    7.486500  8.272500
4    9.344333  8.268667
5   11.202167  8.264833
6   13.060000  8.261000
7   14.890167  8.259500
8   16.720333  8.258000
9   18.550500  8.256500
10  20.380667  8.255000
11  22.210833  8.253500
12  24.041000  8.252000
```